# JavaScript Select Elements with 'required' Attribute

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form with multiple inputs and I need to select all the elements with a "required" attribute. How can I do that? I tried to use the following code but it didn't work.

```
var theForm = document.getElementById('form');
var requiredElements = theform.elements.required;
```

How can I use .querySelectorAll() to select them? A sample of the form is shown below. Thanks a bunch.

```
<form id="form">
 <label for="zip">* Zip Code:</label>
 <input maxlength="10" type="text" name="zip" id="zip">

 <label for="email">* Email:</label>
 <input maxlength="256" type="text" name="email" id="email" required>

 <label for="city">* City:</label>
 <input maxlength="45" type="text" name="city" id="city" required>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
var form = document.querySelector('#form');
var requiredElements = form.querySelectorAll('[required]')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `querySelectorAll`, which returns a nodeset of matched elements, if any.

```
theForm.querySelectorAll('*[required]');
```